# Validate a Filename in R

Tags: r

I'm writing an R function that will take a filename as an input, and write its output to that filename.

I need a helper function to validate that the object passed in as a filename is:

```
1. A character vector and a valid filename
2. In a writable directory
3. Does not already exist
```

Is there a function that already accomplishes all this in the base package or do I need to create such a function myself?

Comment: some combination of `file.access` and `dirname`?

Comment: @fanli I foresee a lot of gotchas and corner cases, I'm hoping something is already written and debugged as opposed to writing something myself